# AEM 6.1 SP1 Drag and Drop Assets to pathbrowser/field in touch UI

Tags: drag-and-drop, aem, drag

Is there a way to drag assets from the side panel to a pathbrowser or a field resulting in the assets path in the field?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this question and wrote a blog post about it here: http://blogs.perficient.com/adobe/2017/02/20/how-to-create-drag-and-drop-experiences-for-aem-authors/

Comment: Thank you for your blog post. Is it possible to create a separate clientlib for just this code and include it in dialogs that need the functionality. It would also be awesome if I could pass a custom DROP_TARGET_SELECTOR parameter. Any idea if this is possible?